# How to fix MalformedPolicyDocument: syntax error in policy generated when use terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am creating an IAM policy to force users to first authenticate using MFA sign in before accessing AWS resources.When I run terraform apply ,I'm getting MalformedPolicyDocument: syntax errors in policy.Any help will be appreciated.thanks

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "AllowViewAccountInfo",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",

```
            "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },       
        "Sid": "AllowManageOwnAccessKeys",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateAccessKey",
            "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
            "iam:ListAccessKeys",
            "iam:UpdateAccessKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowManageOwnSSHPublicKeys",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
            "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
            "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
            "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
            "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowManageOwnGitCredentials",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateServiceSpecificCredential",
            "iam:DeleteServiceSpecificCredential",
            "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
            "iam:ResetServiceSpecificCredential",
            "iam:UpdateServiceSpecificCredential"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowManageOwnVirtualMFADevice",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
            "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowManageOwnUserMFA",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
            "iam:EnableMFADevice",
            "iam:ListMFADevices",
            "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAllExceptListedIfNoMFA",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotAction": [
            "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
            "iam:EnableMFADevice",
            "iam:GetUser",
            "iam:ListMFADevices",
            "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
            "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
            "sts:GetSessionToken"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "BoolIfExists": {
                "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `json` has one `{` missing. If you take this `json` and try to make a policy in console, it will give you the exact position where there is the issue.
Right before `"Sid": "AllowManageOwnAccessKeys",` you are missing `{`.

UPDATED:
The following is an example from official aws doc about using variables.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Action": ["iam:*AccessKey*"],
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/${aws:username}"]
  }]
}
```

You can change your policy according to this.

Comment: i removed it but I think terraform is complaining about the aws:username variable used

Comment: Getting the same error or the error has changed?